# Configuration file with ClickOnce deployment

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I've been trying to modify my application to deploy and update using ClickOnce. I've managed to get the program working but I'm having trouble with the program configuration. My program uses a custom XML configuration file located in the application directory. This raises 2 major problems.

1.) The configuration file is very hard to get to. Without knowledge of how ClickOnce works the user will not be able to locate it.

2.) Currently if I change the configuration file ClickOnce automatically "updates" the configuration file to the original version, destroying my configuration.

Ideally I would like it to move the configuration file to another location and create a start menu shortcut to it next to my application. But if I change the program to do this can I still deploy the application using ClickOnce?

Thanks in advance,

Fr33dan

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put a copy of the configuration in the users app data folder (this can be done on first run) - then have a button in your application which opens it (either externally or in your application)?

Answer (score 1):

You can always store your configuration data in the Application Settings.  This won't get overwritten on every ClickOnce change or update (unless you change the Type of the setting).  You can then create a simple form to update it.  That's the technique many .NET developers use for screensavers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do here to mitigate this as a problem.

Firstly, using what's already there - the configuration data has two parts (excuse me as I'm working from memory) app config and user config. The app config is basically defined when the app is pulled down however the *user* config is just that - you set up the defaults and then, once set by the application on behalf of the user, it won't be overwritten when the app is updated.

It should be straightforward enough to provide a configuration editor - something as simple as a two column grid would be sufficient with a read only label column and an editable value column (although you're going to be somewhat challenged on validation).

Alternatively, if you're happier with a more traditional configuration, then you need precisely 1 user value and that would be the location for the config file... if you don't know if (or can't find the file) prompt to create, dump your default config to the specified location from a resource within you app and then you've got your config file and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

One project I worked on, we made the app download a configuration file from the server it was deployed from (this was done on each startup to cope with if app was added to the Start Menu and cached).   The ClickOnce API gives you the server address.

On another project we just pass a few config values as query strings to the ClickOnce app, these were generated by the Asp.net page that had the link to the app.

This allowed customers to change the config for their site without having to resign etc.
(This does not help with per-user config)